# Convertir de tipo string a time y que vuelva a tipo string

Tags: html, .net, visual, studio

Buen día,

chicos tengo este código

```
var query = (from has in carga.SP_Asistencia_Diaria_2(asistencia.Legajo, Convert.ToString(asistencia.Fecha))
                              
                                 select new ausentismoDTO
                                 {
                                     Agente = has.Agente,
                                     Fecha = Convert.ToString(has.Fecha), 
                                     Legajo = has.Legajo,
                                     Inicio_turno = Convert.ToString(has.Inicio_turno), 
                                     fin_turno = Convert.ToString(has.fin_turno),
                                     cant_horas =has.cant_horas,
                                     ingreso = Convert.ToString(has.ingreso),
                                     egreso = Convert.ToString(has.egreso),
                                     horas = has.horas,
                                     time_falta = has.horas,
                                     Hora_de_conexión = Convert.ToString(has.Hora_de_conexión),
                                     Hora_de_Desconex_ = Convert.ToString(has.Hora_de_Desconex_),
                                     tiempo = has.tiempo,
                                     time_falta_1 = has.time_falta_1

                                 }).ToList();

                    return query;
```

esta consulta pero quiero que fecha me lleve solo la fecha y no el tiempo y que los demás hagan lo contrario soy nueva en programación y las paginas no me dan lo que estoy buscando por favor  lo tuve que convertir de tipo string para que corriera el código

Comment: Tu pregunta no es objetiva, entiendo que quieres convertir un valor a tiempo y retornarlo nuevamente como string, pero hasta alli entiendo te recomiendo dar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) edita o reformula tu pregunta para que sea bien recibida, saludos

Comment: Por favor redacta bien para que se te pueda entender lo que quieres decir